# Solr->ping php-solr-client returning httpStatus 0 when it is up

Tags: solr

About 1 out of every 10 queries seem to return a communication error even though the solr server is up. (I verified this by removing my ->ping() check and all the queries worked.

What could be causing ping to have a communication error?

```
Apache_Solr_Response::__set_state(array(
   '_response' => 
  Apache_Solr_HttpTransport_Response::__set_state(array(
     '_statusCode' => 0,
     '_statusMessage' => 'Communication Error',
     '_mimeType' => 'text/plain',
     '_encoding' => 'UTF-8',
     '_responseBody' => '',
  )),
   '_isParsed' => false,
   '_parsedData' => NULL,
   '_createDocuments' => true,
   '_collapseSingleValueArrays' => true,
))
```

Answer (score 1):

The default timeout is 2 seconds, I changed to 10 and it is working now.

Comment: Good deal - 2 seconds seems kind of low.

Comment: now am facing this issue. Can you please tell me where u updated the timeout